# Нужна помощь с JS отправкой формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 2 куска кода: первый отвечает за проверку полей, второй отправляет форму.

Не получается вставить код отправки после проверки полей. Как это сделать? В JS не силен, очень прошу помощи.

Проверка:

```js
$("#feedback-form").submit(function(e) {

  var ref = $(this).find("[required]");

  $(ref).each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      alert("Required field should not be blank.");

      $(this).focus();

      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
  return true;
});
```

Код отправки формы:

```js
document.getElementById('feedback-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    f = this;
  evt.preventDefault();
  http.open("POST", "http://ravtest1.site88.net/pro-stroy/contacts.php", true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  function cheсk_str(str) {
    if ('.txt-required'.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      $('.msg-form').html("Мало букв");
    }
  }

  http.send("nameFF=" + f.nameFF.value + "&phone=" + f.phone.value + "&contactFF=" + f.contactFF.value + "&messageFF=" + f.messageFF.value);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      $('.msg-form').html("Спасибо за обращение! Мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время.");
      f.messageFF.removeAttribute('value'); // очистить поле сообщения (две строки)
      f.messageFF.value = '';
    }
  }
  http.onerror = function() {
    $('.msg-form').html("Извините, данные не были переданы");
  }
}, false);
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="msg-form"></div>
<form method="POST" id="feedback-form">
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="name">Введите имя</label>
    <input type="text" name="nameFF" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="email">Введите e-mail</label>
    <input required="true" type="email" name="contactFF" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="phone">Введите контактный телефон</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone">
  </div>
  <div class="box-input">
    <label for="vopr">Задайте вопрос</label>
    <input required="true" type="text" name="messageFF" id="vopr">
  </div>
  <div class="box-button">
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
$("#feedback-form").submit(function(e) {
  var ref = $(this).find("[required]")
                   .filter(function (){ return $(this).val() == '' });

  if (ref.length > 0){
    alert("Required field should not be blank.");
    ref[0].focus();

    // return false в обработчике через jquery автоматически подразумевает 
    //  вызов .preventDefault(): http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/4267982
    return false;
  }
});
```